# Changing mass and relative motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, relative-motion

Sand is pouring vertically on a cart at J [kg/sec], from negligable hight. The cart is standing on top of a frictionless surface. What force F do we have to apply to the cart for it to move at a constant speed V?

Well, the answer is: F= V·J

But this is how I tried to solve it:
The cart is moving at a constant speed V, thus relative to the cart the sand is moving at V$'$=-V.
Thus Newton's second law is:

F= $m(t)·\frac{dv}{dt}+V'·\frac{dm}{dt}= V'·J= -VJ$

Which doesn't make sense since this force is in the opposite direction of V. What went wrong? Should V' be an absolute value, as in just the size V?

Comment: Why have you used $V'$ in your equation for $F=\frac{d}{dt}(mV)$ instead of using $V$? If you are calculating the force on the cart, you should be using the velocity of the cart, not the velocity of the sand relative to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you work with a constant mass and you want to calculate something like the force needed to accelerate an object from velocity $v_i$ to $v_f$ in time $t$. So you write down the equation
$$
F = \frac{d}{dt}(mv) = m \frac{dv}{dt},
$$
isolate what you're looking for and solve.

In the case of you question, you want to keep $v$ constant, but you add mass to a cart with initial mass $m_0$. So $dv/dt=0$ but $dm/dt$ isn't. Sand is dropping at a constant rate of $J$, so you add up a mass of $Jt$ and the total mass is $m(t)=m_0+Jt$. Now calculate the force needed:
$$
F = \frac{d}{dt}(mv) = \frac{dm}{dt}v + m\underbrace{\frac{dv}{dt}}_{=0} = Jv.
$$

Comment: Please see tailpiece (starting "It's instructive…" to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The change in momentum of the cart in time $\Delta t$ is $$\text{final momentum - initial momentum} = (m + J \Delta t)v - mv = Jv \Delta t,$$ in which $m$ is the mass of the car at the start of $\Delta t$. So from Newton's second law, the force needed on the cart (in order to maintain its velocity even with the extra mass, that comes without any momentum of its own) is $$F=\frac{Jv \Delta t}{\Delta t} = Jv.$$

Job done.

It's instructive to repeat this calculation for a cart accreting sand that is thrown on to the cart with initial velocity component $v_s$ in the direction of motion of the cart, and to remove the restriction that the cart's velocity is kept constant. Then the mean rate of change of momentum over a time interval $\Delta t$ is $$\frac {\text{final momentum - initial momentum}}{\Delta t} \ =\frac{(m+ \Delta m)(v+\Delta v)-(mv+\Delta m\ v_s)}{\Delta t} $$ in which $v$ is the cart's velocity at the start of $\Delta t$ and $\Delta m$ is the mass of sand accreted in that time. So in the limit as $\Delta t$ goes to zero, the rate of change of momentum of the system is $$F=m \frac{dv}{dt} + (v-v_s) \frac {dm}{dt}.$$ The purpose of this tailpiece is to show that $$F=m \frac{dv}{dt} + v \frac {dm}{dt}$$ is not generally true.